# Laravel Eloquent join with dynamic table name in model

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

I want to run this query in Laravel eloquent Orm.

```
"SELECT a.* from $tbl1 a, $tbl2 b Where a.user_id = b.user_id and a.order_id = 1";
```

Moreover my `$tbl1` name is dynamic and variable $a will be change by requirements.

```
$a = 'user';
$tbl1 = $a . '_order';
```

Now I have two models like

```
Class AB{
  public function b(){
    return $this->hasOne('B','user_id');
  }
}

Class B{
  protected $table = 'user';
  public function ab(){
    return $this->belongsTo('AB','user_id');
  }
}
```

My Controller

```
Class AController{
  public function hello($tbl){
    $a= new AB;
    $a->setTable($tbl);
    $where = ['order_id' => 1];
    $query = $a->with('b')->where($where)->get();
  }
}
```

But it returns AB model table name `abs` as model name is AB but expected table name will be `user_order`